# Extend Wishlist without plugin to work with WooCommerce products

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I've tried lots of plugins, and no one is perfect for me. I finally found a solution, how to add posts to favorites without plugins, and it works for post type **"post"**, but I need woocommerce products too.

I tried to change $args from 'post_type'   => 'post' to 'post_type'   => 'post, product' or 'post_type'   => 'product', but it doesn't add products to favorite page. There are still only added posts.

https://wptrick.ru/kak-sdelat-izbrannye-zapisi/
That's a source, but some words are Cyrillic, so I'll translate.

**1) Add 3 functions to functions.php**

```
    //favorite posts array
    function favorite_id_array() { 
        if (!empty( $_COOKIE['favorite_post_ids'])) {
            return explode(',', $_COOKIE['favorite_post_ids']);
        }
        else {
            return array();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //add to favorite function
    function add_favorite() {
        $post_id = (int)$_POST['post_id'];
        if (!empty($post_id)) {
            $new_post_id = array(
                $post_id
            );
            $post_ids = array_merge($new_post_id, favorite_id_array());
            $post_ids = array_diff($post_ids, array(
                ''
            ));
            $post_ids = array_unique($post_ids);
            setcookie('favorite_post_ids', implode(',', $post_ids) , time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/');
            echo count($post_ids);
        }
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_favorite', 'add_favorite');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_favorite', 'add_favorite');
    
    
    
    //delete from favorite function
    function delete_favorite() {
        $post_id = (int)$_POST['post_id'];
        if (!empty($post_id)) {
            $favorite_id_array = favorite_id_array();
            if (($delete_post_id = array_search($post_id, $favorite_id_array)) !== false) {
                unset($favorite_id_array[$delete_post_id]);
            }
            setcookie('favorite_post_ids', implode(',', $favorite_id_array) , time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/');
            echo count($favorite_id_array);
        }
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_delfavorite', 'delete_favorite');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delfavorite', 'delete_favorite');
```

**2) Adding "Add to favorite"link to your template. For posts it's single.php**

```
   <?php if(in_array($post->ID, favorite_id_array())){ ?>
   <div class="fv_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" title="Already in favorite" ><img src="http://yoursite.com/path-to-your-icon.svg" ><a href="http://yoursite.com/favorite/">In favorite</a></div>
   <?php } else { ?>
   <div class="fv_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" >
      <div class="add-favorite" title="Add to favorite" data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
         <img src="http://yoursite.com/path-to-your-icon.svg">Add to favorite
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

**3) JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //adding to favorite
    $('body').on('click', '.add-favorite', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'favorite',
                'post_id': post_id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.fv_' + post_id).html('<img src="http://yoursite.com/path-to-your-icon.svg" ><a href="http://yoursite.com/favorite/">In favorite</a>');
                $('.num-favorite').html(data);
            },
        });
    });
    //deleting from favorite
    $('body').on('click', '.delete-favorite', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'delfavorite',
                'post_id': post_id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.fv_' + post_id).html('Deleted');
                $('.num-favorite').html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**4) Adding the link to your favorite, wherever you want, in header for example.**

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/favorite/">Favorite <div class="num-favorite"><?php echo count(favorite_id_array()); ?></div> </a>
```

**5. Creating new page template in your theme, favorite.php, then in admin panel create a new page with slug favorite and choose that template for it.**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: favorite
*/
?> 
<?php
   $favorite_id_array = favorite_id_array();
   global $wp_query;
   $save_wpq = $wp_query;
   $args = array(
   'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1,
   'post_type'   => 'post',
   'post__in'   => !empty($favorite_id_array) ? $favorite_id_array : array(0),
    );
   $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
   ?>
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="fv_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
   <div class="delete-favorite" data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" title="Delete from favorite">
      <img src="http://yoursite.com/link-to-your-icon.svg" >Delete
   </div>
</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p>No posts in your favorite</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?> 
 
your pagination code there.
```

Does it work for you? Anybody try it please, I need it, maybe someone needs the same thing too.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me but on the Favorite Template page I see no posts returning. But if I click on "Add to favorite" inside a product and then I refresh it, it says "In favorites" which means the product is saved in cookies.

UPDATE: I changed the query from `'post_type'   => 'post',` to `'post_type'   => 'product',` and it worked!